# How to print values in reverse without the use of arrays nor pointers in C

Tags: c, printing, reverse, radix, ansi-c

I've been working on a code that converts a given number (decimal base) to any other base from 2 to 16.

Clearly, I've come across the issue that the function `base_conversion_it` (it stands for iterative) prints the values in reverse.

I cannot use arrays nor pointers, and everyone on the internet seems to solve this issue like that. My assignment requires making both an iterative and a recursive function (which I did and works).

```c
void base_conversion_it(unsigned int n, unsigned int b) {

    if (n > 0) {

        //bases between 2 and 16
        if (b >= 2 && b <= 16) {

            int r;          //r = remainder
            int q = 1;      //quotient
            int num;        //saves the remainder

            while (q != 0) {

                r = n % b;
                printf("%X", r);

                q = n / b;
                n = q;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might or might not care to note that the argument `n` is in binary, not decimal.  It actually doesn't make much difference, but integers are not stored as decimal numbers inside a computer.

Comment: The constraints of 'iterative, no pointers, no arrays' make it hard to produce an efficient solution. You might need to determine how many digits will be printed, and then arrange to print each digit calculating afresh — which involves multiple loops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've managed to determine how many digits the number will have by doing `k = (log10(n) / log10(b) + 1)` but how do I print them accordingly?

Comment: See the updated answer from 0___________ — the iterative solution is rather neat.  It does have two loops — but my casual thinking was coming up with three loops, the second two nested.  Avoiding that nesting is much better, of course.  Also, beware of possible inaccuracies in floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start converting from the *units* digit.
Maybe start with the most significant digit instead?

```
// It's Undefined Behaviour if `b` is outside the range [2...16]
void base_conversion_it(unsigned int n, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned highestbase = 1;
    while (highestbase * b <= n) highestbase *= b; //possible wrap around and infinite loop

    while (highestbase) {
        printf("%X", n / highestbase);
        n %= highestbase;
        highestbase /= b;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: the only problem is base > 16

Comment: Yeah ... I removed the check (`if (b >= 2 && b <= 16)`) and decided to call it **UB** :)

Comment: @pmg May you further explain why you removed the `if` check?

Comment: If the function is properly documented and the user follows the rules, the `if` is redundant ... like `sqrt(-42)` <== everybody knows not to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry missed iterative.

```
char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

void print(unsigned long long val, unsigned base)
{
    unsigned long long mask = base;
    while(val / mask >= base) mask *= base;
    do
    {
        printf("%c", digits[val / mask]);
        val %= mask;
        mask /= base;
    }while(val);
}

int main(void)
{
    print(45654756453, 10); printf("\n");
    print(45654756453, 16); printf("\n");
    print(45654756453, 24); printf("\n");
    print(45654756453, 2); printf("\n");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W3fGnnhYs

Recursion:

```
char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

void print(unsigned long long val, unsigned base)
{
    if(base <= 16 && base > 1)
    {
        if(val >= base) print(val / base, base);
        printf("%c", digits[val % base]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/84hYocnjv

Comment: The OP has a recursive solution and needs help with an iterative solution that doesn't use arrays or pointers.  This fails on all those counts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler missed that, ammended

Comment: Much better.  The residual array could be fixed by the same technique the OP uses: `printf("%llX", val / mask);` — and it isn't clear that the (constant) array of digits, as opposed to an array used to store the digits as they are discovered, seriously violates the rules.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you can extend it for bases > 16 just adding letters (or rather digits :) ) to the array. "%x" will not work https://godbolt.org/z/84hYocnjv

Comment: Since the problem specification says "any other base from 2 to 16", that isn't a major problem.  For school homework, following the letter of the "no arrays" law may be necessary.  For general work, using the array of digits is perfectly reasonable.  I might use `putchar(digits[val / mask]);` in preference to `printf()`, but that's trivia — and the benefit of using `putchar()` in a multi-threaded world (where stream locking is mandated) is much smaller than was the case historically.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use either arrays (including strings) or recursion, then I think you need to compute the output digits in most-significant-first order.  This is a bit less natural than computing them in the opposite order and reversing the result, but it can be done:

- use a loop to find the place value of the most significant non-zero base-`b` digit of `n`. For example, check the result of dividing `n` by successive powers of `b` until the result is 0, then back off one step.
- In a separate loop, read off the base-`b` digits of `n` one by one, starting with the one at the discovered most-significant position. For each digit,

  1. Divide the current value of `n` by the place value `pv` of the current digit to get a digit value.
  2. Replace `n` with `n % pv`.

  Be careful to continue all the way down to place value 1, as opposed, say, to stopping when `n` becomes zero.